# How can I transfer the part of tabbarOptions code to ClojureScript

Tags: react-navigation, clojurescript

How to use the TabNavigator of the react navigation in ClojureScript? It's really difficult to write navigationOption configuration and I want to know how to reach it.

I have do some efforts to address it, but not suitable. I have learned the mechanism of clojure compiler, so I try best to avoid the rookie mistakes.But it's really difficult to solve the problem of 
anonymous function as the prop to some components. If you write them using `fn`, `#(...)`， the `prop`name will changed when compiled to js.

THe javascript code shows as following:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions:({naviagtion}) => ({
      tabBarLabel: 'home',
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => (
        <TabBarItem
          tintColor={tintColor}
          focused={focused}
          normalImage={require('./assets/home.png')}
          selectedImage={require('./assets/home.png')}
        />
      )
    })
  },
  Content: {
    screen: content,
    navigationOptions:({naviagtion}) => ({
      tabBarLabel: 'content',
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => (
        <TabBarItem
          tintColor={tintColor}
          focused={focused}
          normalImage={require('./assets/content.png')}
          selectedImage={require('./assets/content.png')}
        />
      )
    })
  }
},
{
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#4CB4E7',
    inactiveTintColor: '#FFEE93',
    style: {backgroundColor: '#FFC09F'}
  }
}）
```

And this is my trying:

```clj
(defn tab-navigator []
  (router/create-bottom-tabnavigator
    (clj->js {:HomeScreen
      (clj->js {:screen (r/reactify-component home-screen)
       :navigationOptions (fn [{:keys [navigation]}]
          (clj->js {:tabBarLabel "home"
           :tabBarIcon (fn [{:keys [focused, tintColor]}]
              (tabbar/tab-bar-item tintColor focused (js/require "../resources/assets/home.png") (js/require "../resources/assets/home.png")))}))})
     :Content
      (clj->js {:screen (r/reactify-component content/content)
       :navigationOptions (fn [{:keys [navigation]}]
          (clj->js {:tabBarLabel "conent"
           :tabBarIcon (fn [{:keys [focused, tintColor]}]
              (tabbar/tab-bar-item tintColor focused (js/require "../resources/assets/content.png") (js/require "../resources/assets/content.png")))}))})})
    (clj->js {:tabBarOptions
      {:activeTintColor "#4CB4E7"
       :inactiveTintColor "#FFEE93"
       :style {:backgroundColor "#FFC09F"}}
    })))
```

Please give me a approach or some archive to refer, It's a really big gift.

Comment: Seems like a good translation. What is the error? :)

Comment: The `tintColor` doesn't work anyway. It seems like there is an error in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things :

1. You should use `clj->js` only before the first map
2. You should pass a map for the **tabbar/tab-bar-item**'s properties

I use something like that for projects :

```
(defn tab-navigator []
  (router/create-bottom-tabnavigator
   (clj->js {:HomeScreen {:screen (r/reactify-component home-screen)
                          :navigationOptions
                          {:tabBarLabel "home"
                           :tabBarIcon (fn [{:keys [focused tintColor]}]
                                         (tabbar/tab-bar-item
                                          {:tintColor tintColor
                                           :focused focused
                                           :normalImage (r/as-element [:> rn/Image {:source (js/require "../resources/assets/home.png")}])}))}}})
   (clj->js {:tabBarOptions
             {:activeTintColor "#4CB4E7"
              :inactiveTintColor "#FFEE93"
              :style {:backgroundColor "#FFC09F"}}})))
```

Comment: Yes, it' right what you said, as the all parameters will be passed to a javascript function. Therefore, all things in the parameters must be javascript format, including the anonymous function. We should fix the `:tabBarIcon` as:
```clojure
:tabBarIcon (fn [^obj]
                      (tabbar/tab-bar-item
                         (clj->js  {:tintColor (.-tintColor obj)
                                        :focused (.-focused obj)
                                        :normalImage (r/as-element [:> rn/Image {:source (js/require "../resources/assets/home.png")}])}))
```